# Is there a function to compare two strings from a parameterized point A to point B

Tags: c++, c

I would like to know if, given:

```
string name_a;
string name_b;
```

there would be some already existing function that would allow me to compare two strings for a certain number of characters [like `strncmp()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncmp/), but from a particular index in my `string`.

For instance:

```
int main(){
    string name_a = "Morning";
    string name_b = "Burning";
    if(FUNCTION(name_a.c_str(),name_b.c_str(), NUMBER_OF_CHAR_COMPARED, INDEX_FIRST_CHAR) == 0 ){
        cout << "Same literal" << endl;
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: If you already have `std::string`, why would you demote it to a `const char*` and loose information?

Comment: Because until yesterday I only knew strcmp/strncmp to compare strings, and they ask for char * as parameter ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `std::string` member function [`compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare) has a version with arguments you need:

```
int compare (size_t pos, size_t len, const string& str) const;
```

It starts comparing at `pos` and uses at most `len` characters, so you can use

```
if (name_a.compare(INDEX_FIRST_CHAR, NUMBER_OF_CHAR_COMPARED, name_b) == 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's `strncmp` (and c string offset):

```
strncmp(&name_a.c_str()[index_first], &name_b.c_str()[index_first], length);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using `substr` and `compare` methods

```
if(name_a.substr(INDEX_FIRST_CHAR, NUMBER_OF_CHAR_COMPARED).compare( name_b.substr(INDEX_FIRST_CHAR, NUMBER_OF_CHAR_COMPARED) ) == 0)
```